# javascript-Express-handlebars: Error: Failed to lookup view "" in views directory "views"

Tags: javascript, express, model-view-controller, express-handlebars

[this is my file setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLS5n.png)

This is the full error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "" in views directory "views"
    at Function.render (C:\Users\CHINO\Desktop\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:597:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\CHINO\Desktop\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at exports.Get404 (C:\Users\CHINO\Desktop\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main\controllers\ErrorControlller.js:3:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\CHINO\Desktop\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\CHINO\Desktop\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
    at C:\Users\CHINO\Desktop\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\CHINO\Desktop\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\CHINO\Desktop\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at C:\Users\CHINO\Desktop\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:646:15
    at next (C:\Users\CHINO\Desktop\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:265:14)
```

I m trying to add a payment record to a student management System, every other view works fine but this it's giving some trouble.
I need help, i dont understand what's wrong
the view i m trying to access is /form

**This is the controller:**

```
//controllers/paymentController.js
const Payment = require("../models/Payments");const Student = require("../models/Students");

// Mostrar el formulario para registrar pagos

exports.getPaymentForm = (req, res, next) => {
Student.findAll()
.then((students) => {res.render("payments/form", { students });

})
.catch((err) => {console.log(err);res.status(500).send("Error en el servidor");
});

};

// Guardar el pago en la base de datos

exports.savePayment = (req, res) => {
const { date, amount, concept, receiptNumber, method, studentId } = req.body;

Payment.create({
date,
amount,
concept,
receiptNumber,
method,
studentId,
})
.then((payment) => {
// Renderizar la vista de confirmación con el pago realizado
res.render("payments/confirmation",{
pageTitle: "Confirmación de Pago",
payment: payment,
});

})
.catch((err) => {
console.log(err);
res.status(500).send("Error en el servidor");
});
};
```

**this is the route payment file**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const paymentController = require("../controllers/PaymentController");

// Mostrar el formulario para registrar pagos

router.get("/payments/form", paymentController.getPaymentForm);

// Guardar el pago en la base de datos

router.post("/payments", paymentController.savePayment);

module.exports = router;
```

**i checked if i made a mistake naming the files but it's not that.**
**This is part of app.js**

```
// importar los modelos.

const Courses = require("./models/Courses");

const Families = require("./models/Families");

const Tutors = require("./models/Tutors");

const Students = require("./models/Students");

const Payments = require("./models/Payments");

//importar las rutas.

const student = require("./routes/student");

const families = require("./routes/families");

const courses = require("./routes/courses");

const tutors = require("./routes/tutors");

const payments = require("./routes/payments");

//importar helpers.

const comparador = require("./util/helpers/hbs/comparar");const compare = require("./util/helpers/hbs/compare");

app.engine('hbs', expressHbs.engine({

layoutsDir: "views/layouts",
defaultLayout: "main-layout",
extname: "hbs",
helpers: {

    IgualValor: comparador.IgualValor,
    equals: compare.equals,

},

}));

app.set("view engine", "hbs");app.set("views", "views");// app.set('views, \__dirname + ./views');app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));app.use(express.static(path.join(\__dirname, "public")));

//Inicializacion de las rutas

app.use(student);app.use(courses);app.use(families);app.use(tutors);app.use( payments)
app.use("/", ErrorController.Get404);
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear... failed to lookup an empty route

Comment: What is `=\>` operator?

Comment: i think those were added accidentally when i was giving format to the code lines text to post it here

Comment: i m new to this, i just dont see it, i thought i indicated the routes correctly

Comment: It's not a problem... I instead do not know handlebars.  What happens if you remove the two braces in `res.render("payments/form", { students })` to obtain `res.render("payments/form", students );` ?